Hyperbolic manifolds and their fundamental group
"Let $M$ be a hyperbolic n-manifold, so that $M\cong \pi_1(M)\setminus \mathbb{H}^n$". I see this statement literally everywhere, but I cannot find a source where this is shown. Can anybody please provide an argument of a reference for this result? Specifically, I look for a proof of the following statement:
Given a hyperbolic n-manifold $M$, show that $M\cong \pi_1(M)\setminus \mathbb{H}^n$.
A proof in the case of a hyperbolic surface would also suffice.

Any manifold is the quotient of its universal cover by its fundamental group, so this statement is a special case of a general principle.  So what you are looking for is the statement that a complete simply connected manifold of sectional curvature $-1$ is isometric to the hyperbolic space.  This is a basic result in Riemannian geometry and can be found for instance in

do Carmo, Manfredo Perdigão. Riemannian geometry. Translated from the second Portuguese edition by Francis Flaherty. Mathematics: Theory & Applications. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 1992. xiv+300 pp. ISBN: 0-8176-3490-8


You should add the adjective "complete."
